# Dangerous php functions

Tags: php

I'm storing php functions to a mySQL database from user input, these functions need to be able to be executed.

As we know, this could and will allow Mr hacker to turn a pretty website into Swiss cheese!

These functions are meant to be simple and don't require any advanced php coding. They are more about handling a single array of data.

So if Mr hacker gets into the administrator section id like to filter out any php functions that could do serious damage before saving to the database.

Things like "exec, shell_exec, system, passthru, popen, proc_open, proc_close", anything that can allow outside input like curl need to be removed.

So what else could be dangerous and should be removed?

I found this list as well:
http://blog.eukhost.com/webhosting/dangerous-php-functions-must-be-disabled/

```
apache_child_terminate
apache_setenv
define_syslog_variables
escapeshellarg
escapeshellcmd
eval
exec
fp
fput
ftp_connect
ftp_exec
ftp_get
ftp_login
ftp_nb_fput
ftp_put
ftp_raw
ftp_rawlist
highlight_file
ini_alter
ini_get_all
ini_restore
inject_code
mysql_pconnect
openlog
passthru
php_uname
phpAds_remoteInfo
phpAds_XmlRpc
phpAds_xmlrpcDecode
phpAds_xmlrpcEncode
popen
posix_getpwuid
posix_kill
posix_mkfifo
posix_setpgid
posix_setsid
posix_setuid
posix_setuid
posix_uname
proc_close
proc_get_status
proc_nice
proc_open
proc_terminate
shell_exec
syslog
system
xmlrpc_entity_decode
```

Comment: Whitelisting >>>>>>> blacklisting. And not storing executable code in the DB at all is even better.

Comment: You'd be quite surprised to see which functions can become dangerous in the hands of an experienced programmer :). If you really have to do this (not), use whitelisting as @delnan says.

Comment: If you really want to offer some form of user scripting, I'd suggest doing it with a more easily sandbox-able language, such as Lua.

Comment: A blacklist might get pretty long and hard to maintain.  But a whitelist may be easier having only 3 or 4 possible safe functions in the entire language.  Also, don't forget classes, like COM, DOTNET, Mysqli, PDO, any xml, etc.

Comment: So how do CMS systems like MODX handle there code input then? And whats the point of building things like CodeMirror?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ive decided to go for something like this:

http://mustache.github.com/#demo

This will allow my users format there data in there own way without direct php code.

Answer (score 13):

You should NEVER run a function that is defined by user input. There are millions of ways that a user could disguise a function name that you can not stop. For example you can save a function name into a variable and run the function with the variable.

```
<?php
$test = "readfile";
$test("somePageWithDatabasePassword.php");
?>
```

That is perfectly valid. And if you think you can test for functions run from variables, there are ways around that using chr(), concatenation, hex...etc.

Comment: QFT `You should NEVER run a function that is defined by user input.`

Comment: @FinalForm what is QFT short for?

Comment: @warl0ck "quoted for truth". http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=quoted%20for%20truth

Answer (score 5):

> I'm storing php functions to a mySQL database from user input, these functions need to be able to be executed.

This is an awful idea. It'll be very difficult to compile a list of "safe" functions and PHP is full of local vulnerabilities that could be exploited by anyone knowledgeable enough.

Even white-listing would be very difficult; it would be difficult to detect code like `$a = 'exe'; $a .= 'c'; $a('echo foo');` would be calling `exec`. Consider an alternative strategy that doesn't involve storing executable code.