# Should user data be sanitized before using functions like explode(), strpos(), substr()

Tags: php, security, sanitization

Not to be a paranoid, i was wondering if using client inputs directly with string manipulation functions such as **explode(), strpos(), substr(),...** could be a security issue.

Two years ago, i remember reading that some of these functions use a library that is sensible to specific entries and that it could be used to create new files ect...

i can't find anything about that mentioned in **[OWSAP](http://www.owasp.org/)**

If so what version of PHP is affected by this?

**Edit** 
i haven't found the exact answer yet but this stakeoveflow question is close to mine
[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470760/dangerous-php-functions)

Comment: Affected by what? You need to be more specific to ask that, you know?

Comment: possible security vulnerability of using string manipulation functions without sanitizing the user input first

Comment: Sanitizing user input for *what*, though?

Comment: @bleuscyther: Handling user input data is *always* a possible security vulnerability, you don't need string functions for that, but you might have them. So about which vulnerability do you talk here exactly, we can not discuss possible ones you know? AFAIK you might be talking about (but again that is just assumption, your question is not contructive) the multibyte functions that were flawed in the past and I dunno how well they are tested nowadays. The binary string functions you list might have not been binary safe in the past which should be considered a flaw.

Comment: @hakre i guess i was reading an old post. I don't remember the name of the function nor how it was exploited. i just remember it had to do with string manipulations and arrays. i guess i should have asked a more general question : What string manipulation functions i should worry about and why? :)

Comment: @bleuscyther: Lol, I don't think that this would have made your question *more* concrete.

Answer (score 2):

Having done PHP development for some years and having my code reviewed by people concerned about security, I have not heard of any such needed. So I suspect you do not need to do any sanitation before passing raw user input to these.

You of course need to always sanitize user controlled variables (and for good forms sake all others as well) before constructing anything that gets further evaluation such as SQL or HTML.

Check for validity when you get the values, sanitize and escape where applicable when constructing things with them. Don't do things in between.

Answer (score 2):

> Two years ago, i remember reading that some of these functions use a library that is sensible to specific entries and that it could be used to create new files ect...

You remember incorrectly. PHP's string processing functions, such as `substr()` and `explode()`, are not sensitive to malformed input -- they will always perform the expected manipulations on the string(s) passed in. What you go on to do with the results is your own business, and you may still need to escape / filter / encode / mangle strings as appropriate further down the line. But the string functions are fine.

You're probably thinking of some other function or library, but I can't imagine offhand what it is. For now I'll just say that you don't have anything to worry about.

Comment: The interesting part is *",..."* in the question I'd say.

Comment: i am almost certain you are right about me referring to another function/library. it had to do with strings manipulation, i can't remember it. i'll do more research and update the post.

Comment: it could that string manipulation functions in C/C++ can be unsafe - https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Format_String - https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Format_string_attack

Answer (score 2):

If the data in question is to be inserted into a database, then yes, it SHOULD ALWAYS BE SANITISED.

However, to try and address your question regarding when to sanitise your data, especially in relation to manipulating it, in times of exploding, imploding et al.

It all depends on the data your handling, and without a good example within your question, this will just be guesswork... However, I would generally go for sanitisation first every time. Basically, if you are worried that there could be vulnerabilities in string manipulation functions, then sanitise the string first.

Security can never be overdone, or overcompensated for. The tiny amount of load you add by increasing your security (and I mean tiny), is far outweighed by having a system which you yourself are confident in.

Basically secure it first, worry about whether you needed to afterwards!

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do you think he should sanitize the data if he is not connecting to a database?

Comment: Either by utilising pattern matching for known attack methods, such as HTML/JS/PHP insertion, then either removing or dealing with those in an appropriate manor. Alternatively (and this depends on where the data is coming from, and what it will be used for), stripping tags, converting htmlentities etc.

As said it all depends on what the user entered data will be used for, its common sense, based on each circumstance.

Answer (score 1):

If the user input is inserted into a batabase, it HAS TO BE SANITIZED.
For a little more on that: http://bobby-tables.com/

If the user input is not being inserted into a database, let the user write whatever they want, it wont do your script any harm , and im relatively certain mysql_real_escape_string() only works if there is a connection to a database made previously, otherwise it will toss an error. Correct me if I am wrong though.

And on that note, I may as well cover everything.. Be sure to use PDO connections or mysqlite if you are connecting to a database. As to further prevention of SQL injections and as MYSQL_* functions are deprecated.

Comment: oh please not the bobby tales story again :|

Comment: @OneTrickPony I find it humorous

Comment: If youre going to downvote you ought to tell why

Comment: The question didn't have anything to do with SQL.

Comment: @duskwuff but sanitization does no? I simply put that if its not inserted into a database there really is no need to sanitize it, much less a way to sanitize it. Granted a may have leaned a bit towards SQL in the end, but still