# tools to find inject malicious code?

Tags: php, code-injection

I search a tool to find inject malicious code in my PHP files.
In each PHP file I had this inject:

```
eval(gzinflate(base64_decode('pRlrc9u48bM70/+AaBhTjGmJol5WbNpJE+fuZppLqjid6di...
```

Of course I use the shell to find and replace the inject. But each hour the inject is back. So some PHP file(s) are injected. I've more than 34 websites on this server - each website are injected.

My question now:
Has somebody an idea to find the security hole?
Maybe a online tool or a script which I can check all PHP files?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Someone has rooted your server. Bite the bullet and shut everything down and rebuild it. You do have backups, right?

Comment: no backups.. it isn't my server..... :(

Comment: The fact that the attackers are changing your source files almost certainly indicate they have some sort of shell access. The server host is the one that needs to fix this issue by patching/rebuilding the server. If they are unwilling/unable to do this then you need to find a new host. The fact that this has even happened would make me look at changing hosts anyway unless they were able to give a good explanation for the attack (an unknown/unpatched 0-day exploit was used for instance).

Comment: Okay. I want to change the host/provider. The problem.. I take a backup of my files - find/replace the eval() code and want to upload the files on my new server. Can I be sure that the injection isn't in my code?

Comment: Unfotunately, if you don't have a backup from before the exploits took place, then the only way you can be sure is to validate all your code manually. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470760/dangerous-php-functions) has a list of functions in PHP you should probably keep an eye out for, but even so I wouldn't rely on a `grep` for each of those and consider it safe. Take this on the chin and accept it for what it is: a reminder that you should always keep your own backups.

Comment: Only for info:
it is the timthumb inject.. But this PHP script is deleted everywhere and replace the eval() inject. But now the injection is back?! How? .. oh man...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've used something like: `grep -Rl "eval" .` and `grep -Rl "base64" .` it can be a good start.

Try to search for patterns in the infected files.

Comment: I did that... the eval() code is away. But this eval() code is coming back every hour.. somewhere is a script which do this. But I can't look into ~10.000 files....

Comment: TBH, I searched for patterns in each infected file I found, then used grep -Rl to be sure to remove all occurrences. 
I also searched google for some patterns, and I finally found the name of the bot.
Cleaning it was easier.
But since it was really critical, I payed a company to make sure that the virus was totally removed ^_^